# How can I add node in circular linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

My goal is read text from file with dynamic array, and print out last whatever you want lines with argument "numline". I have to use circular singly linked list for this job. when I run function I get only first line X numline. I'm confused, did I do something wrong with add node partition or traverse and printout partition?

EDiT :  i edited file...

```
    void last(char* numline,char* fileptr)
{

  struct node *start,*newnode,*lastnode;
  struct node *ptr=start;
  char *linebuffer;
  int maxlinelen=512;
  int i=0;
  int j;

  FILE *fp;
  linebuffer=(char*)malloc(maxlinelen * sizeof(char*));
  if(linebuffer==NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Command: last:Memory allocating failed for linebuffer\n");
      exit(1);
    }


      if((fp=fopen(fileptr,"r"))!=NULL)
    {
      start=NULL;

      while((fgets(linebuffer,maxlinelen,fp))!=NULL)
         {
           while(strlen(linebuffer)==maxlinelen-1)
         {
           maxlinelen*=2;
           linebuffer=realloc(linebuffer,maxlinelen * sizeof(char));
           if(linebuffer==NULL)
             {
               fprintf(stderr,"Command: last: Memory reallocating failed for linebuffer\n");
               exit(1);
             }
           fgets(linebuffer+(maxlinelen/2-1),(maxlinelen/2)+1,fp);
         } 

           if(start==NULL)
         {
           newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

               strcpy(newnode->data,linebuffer);
               printf("linebuffer newnoda kopyalandi\n");

               start=newnode;
           newnode->next=newnode;
           // start=newnode;
           i++;
           printf("ikinciburda");
         }
           else{
         newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         strcpy(newnode->data,linebuffer);
         lastnode=start;
         while(lastnode->next!=start)
           {
             lastnode=lastnode->next;
           }
         lastnode->next=newnode;
         newnode->next=start;
         i++;
           }
         }
      printf("toplam line sayisi :%d\n",i);
         ptr=start;                           //<----- i added this line
      for(j=i-(atoi(numline));j<i;j++)
        {
          ptr=ptr->next;
        }
      while(ptr!=start)
        {
          printf("%s\n",ptr->data);
          ptr=ptr->next;
        }
      fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines

```
  while(start->next!=start)
  {
      printf("%s\n",start->data);
      /// especially this one
      start=start->next;
  }
```

look suspicious.

On the first iteration you're assigning the `start->next` to `start` and immediately you get out of the loop (because, obviously, `start == start->next`).

All you should do is to create a `struct node* ptr`, assign start to it and then make a `ptr = ptr->next` "totallines" - "numline" times:

```
 struct node* ptr = start;

 for(j = atoi(numline) ; j < i ; j++) { ptr = ptr->next; }

 while(ptr != start)
 {
     printf("%s\n", ptr->data);
     ptr = ptr->next;
 }
```

Of course, you should check to `numline <= totaline` - I've omitted this check for brevity.

Important EDIT:

After inserting the

```
   for(j = i - atoi(numline) ; j < i ; j++)
   {
       // debug statement
       printf("skip %s\n", ptr->data);
       ptr = ptr->next;
   }
```

I've noticed, that the linked list is constructed incorrectly - the above iteration gives only the first line.

EDIT2 (Some notes):

Your error handling code is nice and the dynamic buffer for indeterminate line length is also good, by the code becomes quite lengthy and it is not so easy to look for the problem. I guess many people came over this answer just because so much is written and most of it is irrelevant to the linked list which, by the way, is *not* defined in the code. My guess is

```
 struct node
 {
     struct node* next;
     char data[SomeBigNumber];
 };
```

EDIT3:  List construction

The code in "add-last-node" part is even trickier, the mess with lastnode/newnode should be clarified.

And the error is here:

```
        /// once again, here lastnode->next IS start, as you want it to be
        lastnode->next=start;
        /// and this condition is always false (see the previous line)
        while(lastnode->next!=start)
        {
            lastnode=lastnode->next;
        }
```

You have commented out the line `//lastnode = start;`, but it should be right before the loop to reach the last element.

The `// add additional nodes` must be:

```
    else {  //add additional nodes
        newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(newnode->data,linebuffer);

        lastnode=start;
        while(lastnode->next!=start) { lastnode=lastnode->next; }

        lastnode->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=start;
        i++;
    }
```

And, of course, looking for the last element each time you insert the node is an overkill. You should just keep the `lastnode` always pointing to the last element (or NULL, when the list is initially empty).

Comment: +1. Your code being much easier to read than the OP, is the initial for-loop to find the "first" entry in the circular list ? Just curious, as I would think just starting with `ptr = start->next;` provided start is not null would clearly circumnavigate all the entries.

Comment: @viktor latypov  i edited my codes. but im getting seg. fault.  im really confuse circular linked list. i already did edit 2.

Comment: @WhozCraig  i did your advise i getting flag printouts but when reach for(j...) loop seg fault!

Comment: @ccc: I've fixed your linked list code (see EDIT3), you were looking for the end-of-list incorrectly. I've compiled and tested you program, my version works.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov  i edited my code you can see it. but im still getting segmentation fault.  something still wrong but. i couldn't find it. what u think ?

Comment: @ViktorLatypov  i added ptr=start; you can see it edit my first code, function is working but when i enter 3 its has to be give to me last 3 lines but its printout all lines except first 3 lines. example my text file total 8 lines, when i enter 3 its giving to me 4-5-6-7-8 lines

Comment: i got it, thank you Victor !!  i edited for(j=i-(i-atoi(numline));j<i;j++)  its works now!  thanks again